# What's the game with a 5x5 array of words, players who give clues, and players who guess the words?

Tags: identify-this-game

I played this game, with two teams, each with a clue-giver and one or more guessers. The clue-givers knew which 8 of the 25 words belonged to their team, and which 8 belonged to the other team. Each round the clue-giver gives a single-word clue to one or more of his team's words. Each round the guessers try to guess which word or words the guesser meant.

I thought the game was called "Codewords", but I don't see that on Amazon. It had a spy theme.

Please can you tell me the correct name of this game?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're thinking of [Codenames](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014Q1XX9S).